# spark.driver.extraClassPath Multiple Jars

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use Spark via Python to access (via JDBC) a PostGres database and a MSSQL database in the same session. In the spark-defaults.conf file I can get one or the other to work but not both.

These two work independently:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar

spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```

I tried these three and neither works (I get the "no suitable driver" error):

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/

spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar sqljdbc4.jar

spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use multiple jars you need to chain them together. If you're running Linux, the chain operator is `:`, on Windows its `;`.

For example, on Linux your `extraClassPath` would be:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar:/Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```

On Windows:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar;/Users/myusername/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```